Prime ng table angular project is not starting
I am trying to set the primeng table project in my local.
Project codebase: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo?file=package.json
Step1:  Installed Node version 16 and tried to start with ng serve command was getting the below exception
Exception:
    PS G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo> ng build
    Node.js version v16.20.2 detected.
    The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

Step2 : So I upgraded the node version to 18, and tried to start it with "ng serve" command but its failing with below exception. Can someone please explain what I am missing here
Exception :
[error] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:22:22
    at G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:9:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:13:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:21:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\typescript.js:15:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\index.js:25:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\package-chunk-sort.js:4:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\index-file\write-index-html.js:13:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:29:28)
    at G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:114:61
    at async WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.loadBuilder (G:\Angular\primeng-tablefilter-demo\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:114:26)


please share the contents of package.json

Did you upgrade to version 18.3, or version 18? The error specifies version 18.3, but in your post you said you upgraded to version 18

Did you re-install the node_modules folder?
